# toggle with jQuery 1.8.3

Tags: javascript, jquery

Create toggle with jQuery 1.8.3 like this

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showmenu1').click(function() {
                $('.menu1').slideToggle("fast");
        });
   
   $('#showmenu2').click(function() {
                $('.menu2').slideToggle("fast");
        });
   
   $('#showmenu3').click(function() {
                $('.menu3').slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showmenu1">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu1" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="showmenu2">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu2" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="showmenu3">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu3" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

how can i reduce the above jQuery code?

Comment: The better question is why would you want to?  Although the included answers would work, if you ever rearrange your dom structure then you've broken the code.  Keeping it the way you have it makes it safer and more readable.

Comment: Because this is really a code review question, it's not necessarily on-topic for SO and there's a good chance it will be closed. It would be more appropriate to ask it on [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @twernt please don't bother flagging for migration. It's already answered, and none of anything on this page is a decent fit for [codereview.se]. The question would need a better description, at a minimum. And less example-ish.

Comment: @Mat'sMug no problem -- I didn't flag it d(-_-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a common class and use next()

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-item').on("click", function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showmenu1" class="menu-item">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu1" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="showmenu2" class="menu-item">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu2" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="showmenu3" class="menu-item">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu3" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

or if the menu is not right next to it, use a data attribute

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggles]').on("click", function() {
        var sel = $(this).data("toggles");
        $(sel).slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showmenu1" data-toggles=".menu1">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu1" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="showmenu2" data-toggles=".menu2">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu2" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="showmenu3" data-toggles=".menu3">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu3" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of IDs change to `class` attribute and use `$(this)` context and refer to next div to show:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.showmenu').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showmenu">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="showmenu">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="showmenu">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can minimize your jQuery code **without changing your HTML** :

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^=showmenu]').click(function() {
        $(this).next('[class^=menu]').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showmenu1">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu1" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="showmenu2">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu2" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="showmenu3">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu3" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li>Button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```